# How to deduce the inequality to show that $\frac{\pi(x)}{x} \to 0$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

[image]

I'd like to answer (why?) question above.

What I've tried is:

First, I guess that $1- (\kappa/2)$ might have been related to $\frac{x_m - (\kappa/2) x_m}{x_m}$.

and we know that $(\kappa/2)x_m \lt \pi(x_m) - \pi(x_{m-1})$.

So $x_m - (\kappa/2) x_m \gt x_m - \pi(x_m) + \pi(x_{m-1})$.

On the right hand side, it can be interpreted as the number of composites $\le x_m$ and primes $\le x_{m-1}$.

I couldn't relate this with the product of primes in $(x_{m-1}, x_m]$.

Could you give me a hint?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think your excerpt makes sense. $\prod_p (1-1/p)=0$ doesn't depend on $\pi(x)/x\to 0$.

Comment: @reuns He already showed that $\limsup_{x \to \infty} \frac{\pi(x)}{x} \le \prod_{k=1}^{\infty} (1- \frac{1}{p_k})$, where $p_k$ is a prime for all $k$. sorry, I should have added it.

Comment: If you say so. Why not show the arguments? Your (why?) is just that $(1-1/x_m)^{c x_m} \to e^{-c}$ as $x_m\to \infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $p_k$ denote the $k$-th biggest primes in $(x_{m-1}, x_m]$,

and each $p_k$ is distinct for $k = 1,2, \dots, \lfloor\kappa/2\rfloor+1$.

For each $k$, we can show that

$$\left(1-\frac{1}{p_k}\right) \lt \left(1- \frac{1}{x_m -(k-1)}\right)=\frac{x_m - k}{x_m -(k-1)}$$

Multiplying for all primes in $(x_{m-1}, x_m]$ gives us

$$\prod_{x_{m-1} \lt p \le x_m}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)\le \prod_{k=1}^{\lfloor\kappa/2\rfloor+1}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right) \lt \prod_{k=1}^{\lfloor\kappa/2\rfloor+1}\left(1- \frac{1}{x_m - (k-1)}\right)\lt \frac{x_m - (\kappa/2) x_m}{x_m}$$

So it's done.